# Uploading items to a personal OneDrive shared folder

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

OneDrive user A shares a folder with OneDrive user B, and B can access that folder by using the share id.
For example using the graph explorer

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/{shareId}
```

yields

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#shares/$entity",
    "id": "{shareId}",
    "name": "ASharedFolder",
    "owner": { ... }
}
```

Now, B wants to upload a new file to ASharedFolder.

Reading the [OneDrive docs for upload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_put_content) I have tried

```
PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/{shareId}/driveItem/children:/SomeFile.txt:/content
Content-Type text/plain
some text goes here
```

as well as

```
PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/{shareId}/items/{sharedItemId}:/SomeFile.txt:/content
Content-Type text/plain
some text goes here
```

but both yield "BadRequest", "Unsupported segment type..."

Edit: I have now played out this scenario in the [OneDrive Web UI](https://onedrive.live.com/) using two different browsers for OneDrive users A and B, so I know that it is possible (without first adding the shared folder to B's own root), but I need some help figuring out the right request for the OneDrive REST API.

Does anyone know?

Comment: Have you tried `PUT /drives/{shareId}/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content`?

Comment: Yes, I just did. Thanks for suggesting it. Unfortunately, it yields

`"error": { "code": "invalidRequest", "message": "The item does not reside in the drive", … }`

Also `GET /drives/{shareId}`

yields 

`"ObjectHandle is Invalid"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the possibility of uploading files to a shared folder on OneDrive belonging to another user.  I did not have any problems to achieve it using [GraphExplorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

Here is what I did:

1. I got a list of shared files and folders:

`GET /me/drive/sharedWithMe`

Returned (some of the data has been omitted):

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(driveItem)",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
            "id": "<itemId>",
            "name": "Folder name",
            "parentReference": {
                "driveId": "<myUserId>",
                "driveType": "personal"
            },
            "remoteItem": {
                "id": "<remoteItemId>",
                "name": "Folder name",
                "createdBy": 
                    "user": {
                        "displayName": "Other user name",
                        "id": "<otherUserId>"
                    }
                },
                "folder": {
                    "childCount": 0
                },
                "parentReference": {
                    "driveId": "<otherUserId>",
                    "driveType": "personal"
                },
                "shared": {
                    "owner": {
                        "user": {
                            "displayName": "Other user name",
                            "id": "<otherUserId>"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

2. Then I preformed PUT request with the following data:

`PUT /drives/{otherUserId}/items/{remoteItemId}:/test.txt:/content`

```
Content-Type: text/plain
The contents of the file goes here.
```

Response: `Success - Status Code 201`

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives('<otherUserId>')/items/$entity",
    "id": "<itemId>",
    "name": "test.txt",
    "size": 35,
    "createdBy": {
        "application": {
            "displayName": "Graph explorer"
        },
        "user": {
            "displayName": "My user name",
            "id": "<myUserId>"
        }
    },
    "parentReference": {
        "driveId": "<otherUserId>",
        "driveType": "personal",
        "id": "<parentReferenceId>",
        "name": "Folder name",
        "path": "/drives/<otherUserId>/items/<parentReferenceId>"
    },
    "file": {
        "mimeType": "text/plain"
    }
}
```

Then, on the subsequent `GET /me/drive/sharedWithMe` request, the value of the *childCount* of the folder has been increased to 1.

**NOTE:**

The `\shares` endpoint only allows [GET requests](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/shares_get) to access a shared DriveItem or a collection of shared items. It does not allow to create new items.

Comment: Ad the NOTE in the reply: I have managed to create a subfolder using `POST /shares/<shareId>/items/<remoteFolderId>/children`, but using the local (and apparently ghostly) itemId of the shared folder retrieved via `GET /me/drive/sharedWithMe` in `PUT /me/drive/items/<itemId>:/FileFromB.txt:/content` returned `"generalException", "message": "Proxying for sync ghost items is not implemented."`.

Comment: you mention that the `/shares` endpoint does not allow for creation of items. Do you know then how to anonymously create items in a publicly shared folder? I would be grateful, if you could take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52186529/7919086 :-)