# Anonymously uploading to a publicly shared folder on OneDrive

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

What is the REST API call to anonymously upload to a publicly shared folder on OneDrive?

I have tried sharing a folder both thru the OneDrive Web UI creating a link attributed with: "Anyone with this link can edit this item", and using the REST API:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/items/{sharedFolderId}/createLink
Content-type: application/json
{
    "type": "edit",
    "scope": "anonymous"
}
```

In both cases, I can read from the shared folder without logging on by

```
GET https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/shares/{shareId}/items/{sharedFolderId}
```

I can also read the permission itself using

```
GET https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/shares/{shareId}/items/{sharedFolderId}/permissions
```

=>

```
{
    "@odata.context":"https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/$metadata#shares('{shareId}')/items('{sharedFolderId')/permissions",
    "value":
    [
        {
            "id":"{permissionId}",
            "link":
            {
                "application":
                {
                    "displayName":"{my own app}",
                    "id":"{short app id}"
                },
                "type":"edit",
                "webUrl":"https://1drv.ms/u/{shareId}"
            },
            "roles":["write"],
            "shareId":"{shareId}",
            "expirationDateTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "hasPassword":false
        }
    ]
}
```

However trying to upload a file or create a subfolder, i.e.

```
PUT https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/shares/{shareId}/driveItem:/{filename}:/content
Content-type: text/plain
some text goes here
```

or

```
POST https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/shares/{shareId}/items/{sharedFolderId}/children
Content-type: application/json
{
    "name": "TestFolder",
    "folder": { }
}
```

both fail as unauthorized calls - but isn't the whole point of an "edit" link with "anonymous" scope that "anyone with this link can edit this item"?

I have tried various combinations of `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0` instead of `https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0` and `/drives/{driveId}` instead of `/shares/{shareId}` as well as `/shares/{shareToken}`, where `shareToken` is the "u!"-encoding of the `webUrl` from the `link` in the permission.

So far without being able to figure out the right REST API call. I hope someone is able to help :-)

You can download my [TestOneDrive](http://dev.dbquity.com/stackoverflow/testonedrive.zip) Visual Studio test project to reproduce the issues. It also contains initialization code to create and share the folder.

Comment: I think this is by design. You can submit an feature request on the user voice.

Comment: Well, if it was by design, I would expect the `createLink` request for `{ "type": "edit", "scope": "anonymous" }` to fail to begin with.
Does anyone know for a fact whether anonymously uploading to a publicly shared folder is supported on OneDrive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to no guys from Product Group following this and no official docs announced this, so I suggest you to submit an feature request first on [UserVocie](https://onedrive.uservoice.com/) or vote up an existing one close to your issue.

Comment: Thank you for returning so quickly to me, @SeiyaSu! I have followed your excellent suggestion here: https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/913708-onedrive-developer-platform/suggestions/35363749-allow-upload-to-shared-folder-without-requring-use. I encourage everybody to vote for it :-)

Answer (score 0):

For people who are coming across this in 2023, following is from MS Graph [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/shares_get?view=odsp-graph-online):

> For OneDrive for Business and SharePoint, the Shares API always requires authentication and cannot be used to access anonymously shared content without a user context.

The keyword here is "without a user context". If I anonymously open shared OneDrive link in my browser and then make MS Graph request to get shared items - I receive expected response. If I do not open shared link first, MS Graph response is 401 unauthenticated. Apparently, MS OneDrive web application creates "Guest Contributor" user context (and, I assume, assigns access token for that Guest User).

This makes me wonder, is it possible to get Microsoft account guest token as it is described in [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/user-token)?

Otherwise, the only solution would be either to use Guest Accounts, or handle the anonymous requests via API client access. Both result in inefficiency and additional code.